# column does not exist in derived_table1 after sql join

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I wrote this sql code to query data in redshift

```
Select
  tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio, cn
From
(
  SELECT
    tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio
  from
    fct.st_member_development as st_member_development
  inner join
  (
    SELECT
      tenant_name as tn, fk_organization_unit as fk, type, date as dt, contract_count as cn
    from
      fct.st_contract_development
  )
    u
      on  st_member_development.tenant_name =u.tn
      and st_member_development.fk_organization_unit =u.fk
      and st_member_development.date =u.dt
)
  x
limit 5
```

I got the following error
ERROR: column "cn" does not exist in derived_table1

how could I fix this please

Comment: I've edited your question to use a layout that's more readable.  By using indents *(at the very lest)* it then becomes very clear.  `u` has a column called, `cn`, but `x` doesn't select it, so of course the outer query can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the column `cn` in inner query.

```
Select
  tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio, cn
From
(
  SELECT
    tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio, cn
  from
    fct.st_member_development as st_member_development
  inner join
  (
    SELECT
      tenant_name as tn, fk_organization_unit as fk, type, date as dt, contract_count as cn
    from
      fct.st_contract_development
  )
    u
      on  st_member_development.tenant_name =u.tn
      and st_member_development.fk_organization_unit =u.fk
      and st_member_development.date =u.dt
)
  x
limit 5
```

Comment: Other than the picking up the formatting changes I made, this doesn't do anything the previous answer does.  In fact, the previous answer actually explains what the problem is, and the answer does not.

Comment: @MatBailie sorry, my window was open for some times. So another answer were provided by then. I am not an redshift expert, but in that answer aliases for subqueries are missing. Is it ok? Then I should remove my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because column `cn` is missing from the second `SELECT`. Try this:

```
Select tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio, cn

From (
SELECT tenant_name, date, fk_organization_unit, active_member_per_studio, cn   
from fct.st_member_development as st_member_development

inner join
(SELECT tenant_name as tn, fk_organization_unit as fk, type, date as dt, contract_count as cn from fct.st_contract_development) u
on  st_member_development.tenant_name =u.tn and st_member_development.fk_organization_unit =u.fk and st_member_development.date =u.dt
)
limit 5
```